# Property 'wallets' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & WalletModalProviderProps'. How can i fix it?

Tags: reactjs, solana, tsx, wallet

im actually working on a solana wallet adapter in react, i follow tutorials who use the solana github code part, actually, in this code part, vscode tell me that there is an error, but idk where ?

```
const Context : FC<{children: ReactNode}> = ({children}) => {
  // const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet;
  // const endpoint = useMemo(() => clusterApiUrl(network), [nertwork])
  const endpoint = "localhost:8899"; // local cluster override

  const wallets = useMemo( () => [
    new PhantomWalletAdapter(),
    new SolflareWalletAdapter(),
    new GlowWalletAdapter(),
    new SlopeWalletAdapter(),
    new TorusWalletAdapter()
  ], []);

  return (
    <ConnectionProvider endpoint={ endpoint }>
      <WalletModalProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
        <WalletModalProvider>{children}</WalletModalProvider>
        </WalletModalProvider>
        </ConnectionProvider>
  )
}
```

the **wallets** in <WalletModalProvider **wallets**={wallets} autoConnect> is considered as an error

Im using the v18.16.0 of node

thx everyone

I dont know what do i have to try there, i checked the official solana repo and its exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -->

```
const Context : FC<{children: ReactNode}> = ({children}) => {
  const endpoint = clusterApiUrl(WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet); // change network as needed

  const wallets = useMemo(() => [
    new PhantomWalletAdapter(),
    // Add other wallet adapters here...
  ], []);

  return (
    <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
      <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
        <WalletModalProvider>
          {children}
        </WalletModalProvider>
      </WalletProvider>
    </ConnectionProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hello batman, thanks for your answer, i pasted ur code and its still telling me that the property doesnt exist :/

Comment: Have you imported `WalletModalProvider` from the correct package?

Comment: Yep, from @solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui

Comment: Can you update the code with all the imports as well?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Add the complete code

Comment: from the solana git hub ? i did it

Comment: But where are the `import` s ?

Comment: i didnt write it in my post but i have all the import in my code

Comment: Yes that's what I want to check. There are some other required packages in the @solana/wallet-adapter family to work.

Comment: `import { ConnectionProvider, WalletProvider} from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { WalletModalProvider, WalletMultiButton} from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui";
import {
  PhantomWalletAdapter,
} from "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets";
import React, {FC, ReactNode, useMemo} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui/styles.css';
import { UnsafeBurnerWalletAdapter } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets';
import { clusterApiUrl } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { WalletAdapterNetwork } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-base';`

Comment: Try my updated code.